# DSAS Error, Optional field not found in baseline layer: Baseline.Group

Tags: digital-shoreline-analysis-system

I wanted to cast transect and when I tried so, the window appears that I have an error that the Baseline.Group is not found.

Here I attached my Cast Transect window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I went back into the attribute automator and added both optional and required fields through the again. Repopulated the data. solved the problem.